# Functional programming and ES6 array subclassing

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm subclassing an array in Javascript ES6 like this:

```
export class MyList extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
  }
}
```

though, once I use functional methods like `map` or `filter`, they'll return a normal Javascript array again.

```
let myList = new MyList();
myList[0] = {id: 'a', name: 'Tom'};
myList[1] = {id: 'b', name: 'Alice'};

let mapedList = myList.map((elem) => elem.name);

console.log(myList instanceof MyList); // true
console.log(myList instanceof Array); // true

console.log(mapedList instanceof MyList); // false
console.log(mapedList instanceof Array); // true
```

So how can I properly subclass a Javascript Array without running into all those problems?

Comment: This is a common subclassing issue if the original class returns new objects.  I'm guessing you'd have to override every method that returns an array and convert that array to your type of object.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this. Lets say I just want all methods return a MyList object instead of an array? Someone must have thought about this right?

Comment: Not that I know of.  It's possible for the original object to create a new object of the same type that the original was (I've done that in my own object hierarchy) so this problem is handled automatically, but if the Array object doesn't already do that, then I don't know how you can add it automatically other than overriding every method that returns a new array.

Comment: Actually an ES6 `map` function should return instances of the subclass. Probably your transpiler just doesn't support that yet (subclassing builtins is complicated).

Comment: Wouldn't you actually really run into problems if `this.idIndex` was a `MyList` (with an `.idIndex` of `undefined`s with an `.idIndex` that throws when being created…)?

Comment: I removed it from the example to make things clearer. @jfriend00 can you point me to the implementation of the subclassing you did?

Comment: You basically can't subclass Array, at least not with current versions of ES6 transpilers and runtimes. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to write an array that has a special index so that an element can be fetched with O(1) (like in a normal object). But since JS objects are not ordered I can't use them

Comment: @TimDau: How would an array with ids help you with that?

Comment: I think you should probably explain your actual problem in more detail and we can probably help you solve it without using Array sublcassing.  Also, you will have to state whether you're using a transpiler or whether you're running real ES6 code because subclassing built-in objects is one thing that transpilers can't necessarily do the same as real ES6 code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a small `static` function called `from`, which can *convert* the resulted `Array` to `MyList` using ECMAScript 2015's `Reflection API`.

Your `class` will look like this:

```js
export class MyList extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }

  static from(arr) {
    Reflect.setPrototypeOf(arr, new MyList);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

And then, in your code, you just have to wrap the `map` call in `from` function call like this:

```js
let mapedList = MyList.from(myList.map((elem) => elem.name));
```

You can also modify it to support more types of `objects` as `Array.from` does.